# What has caused this error to keep emerging and how to prevent it from keep happening

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication

I'm still new to Angular and recently I have been trying to make a login system that goes to another page. But unfortunately, I can't quite get to that stage yet as I have this problem in my code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authservice: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

the error that i keep getting from the vscode is:

> Cannot find module '../../services/auth.service' or its corresponding type declarations

However, when i try to login to another page, it does not share the similar error.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-userinfo',
  templateUrl: './userinfo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userinfo.component.css']
})
export class UserinfoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authservice: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your directory structure is correct?

Comment: be sure you defined your service as:`@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root',})`. The error looks like as you try to import the services in one module in the "imports" array. A service in not necesary declare or use as provider in any place -only is neccesary import in the .ts that you use it-

Comment: Eliseo, I have already defined my service like you said earlier, but the error is still the same.